# c++ qt 5.5 src_dir and how to include headers

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I've currently got a QT5.5 subdirs project setup, containing so far a core library, a QT GUI app and soon in the future a tests project (probably using unittest++).

I'm following the guide for setting up the project structure: http://dragly.org/2014/03/13/new-project-structure-for-projects-in-qt-creator-with-unit-tests/

So far, the directory structure is as follows:

```
/Project
    src/
        app/
            app.pro (app project, depends on core.pro)
            main.cpp
            mainwindow.cpp
            mainwindow.h
        core/
            core.pro (lib project)
            class.h
            class.cpp   
    tests/ (future test project location
    Project.pro (subdirs)
    defaults.pri
```

The following is my defaults.pri file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/src
SRC_DIR = $$PWD
```

However, I'm not sure if I'm getting the #include directives right.

When using the #include, I have to do #include "../core/class.h". I'm not sure if this is the best way to go?? My understanding was because it's a lib, I just reference the header file as if it was within the lib, rather than location on disk?

Would namespaces solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `/Project/src` as include dir for your project (-I on most compilers), you can include it with:

```
#include <core/class.h>
```

Comment: The INCLUDEPATH part is the generic way rather than the -I switches.